# rails: Best practices to implement admin API for angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs, api

I am about to implement an API for an admin panel for a single page app based on angular. The admin panel will have many sections and sub-sections where some sub-sections are stored at the same model and some have a model of their own. Each sub-section of the admin panel will have an update button.

As I see it, I have a few ways I could implement this.

**Method 1**

Single controller where each sub-section will have a namespace in the params. For instance, params[:color][...] for the colors, params[:links][...] for the links.

Then in the update action of the controller I will split the params and save the models.

Simple, but not very flexible and hard to return an error.

**Method 2**

Separate controllers per model. So this is kind of a mix because some sections in the admin panel will post to the same controller with the relevant param.

**Method 3**

A controller per section. Each section of the admin panel will have a route and controller. So I might have controllers which the same code. I could use concerns in this case.

I tend to go with Method 2, but I am not sure what is the best practice here. Would love some tips.

Thanks!